# Entity Framework get specific column from a string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Web API project that uses Entity Framework. I have an action `api/account` that given an ID returns that account.

There is an additional parameter that can be provided which is what fields to be returned e.g. `api/account?field=name`

I'm trying to work out the best way of translating from this string input to Entity Framework. I know I can use `.Select()` to only get certain columns but that takes in a `Func` and the only way I can think of getting from the string to a `Func` is by using Reflection. This seems like it will be a peformance hit if I have to do Reflection for every property passed in, is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: If you really need to return a dynamic subset of the columns in your API, I would still select them all from the DB and use some code (probably just if/else statements) to map the columns you want to the object you are returning from the API.

Comment: I just saw your older question. I'd advise you not to build dynamic queries to populate drop downs. Just create a specific endpoint for each type of data you need. AccountID/Name only vs all account details.

Comment: @Ryan that's what I was thinking, creating a separate endpoint for these. I was just thinking about going the dynamic route for future proofing if I need to get specific fields later.

Comment: Are you sure you need Reflection? It seems that you can do this with Expressions (see Expression.MakeMemberAccess and the like)

Comment: For situations like this, you can build a sql and execute it through the context.Database.  using (var context = new myContext())
                {
                    result = context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql).ToList();
                }

Comment: How about using odata in web api, which you can have dynamic select from you endpoint refer this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library System.Linq.Dynamic from Nuget, and this query

```
var selectStatement = string.Format("new ({0},{1})", field1, field2);
var result = db.Users.Select(selectStatement).ToListAsync().Result;
```